# Wanted to know if the user is online or not firebase , if i have the base url and UID

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am writing a function in Node js and got the list of all users uid's, and wanted to know if the user is online or not .Not able to figure out how to do it with .info/connected  . Please help

Comment: There are several ways to achieve it, the most straight forward would be to manage yourself a connected `boolean` _online_ field in your database. You should search something like "presence sysetem firebase" in google. This article might help : https://firebase.googleblog.com/2013/06/how-to-build-presence-system.html

Answer (score 0):

.info/connected shows you if the current device is connected to the firebase server.
if you want to check if someone is online, you can add a node in each firebase user for example isOnline, whenever someone is logging in the value will become true. and if he/she will logout it will become false.